# Issue with this code of processing.py

Tags: python, processing

I'm replacing the pixels of this green screen.
It just doesn't work...

```
def setup():
    size(852,480)

def draw():
    image1 = loadImage("l.jpg")
    image(image1,0,0,852,480)
    loadPixels()
    pixels1 = pixels[0:]

    image2 = loadImage("r.jpg")
    image(image2,0,0,852,480)
    loadPixels()
    pixels2 = pixels[0:]

    for i in range(0,width*480):
        r = red(pixels[i])
        g = green(pixels[i])
        b = blue(pixels[i])
        if g > 220:
            pixels[i] = pixels1[i]
        else:
            pixels[i] = pixels2[i]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per the [documentation](https://processing.org/reference/loadPixels_.html), whenever you call `loadPixels()`, you must follow up with a call to [`updatePixels()`](https://processing.org/reference/updatePixels_.html).